# Missing line feed when creating class from custom template

Tags: java, templates, intellij-idea

I made a custom template for IntelliJ IDEA because I have a class type which has some custom stuff in it and I didn't want to write it manually all the time.

Here's the template code:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
import xxx.data.${EntityName};

public interface ${NAME} extends BasicService<${EntityName}> {

}
```

Basically, this template is working well except one bug (I guess it is): when I create a file based on this template, it looks like this:

```
package xxx.persistence.service;import xxx.data.Notification;

public interface NotificationService extends BasicService<Notification> {

}
```

As you can see, the `import` statement is on the same line as the package definition, even though I wrote it on the next line in my template definition. Did I miss something for creating custom templates? The built-in Java class template looks like this:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} {
}
```

It does not contain imports, but between the package and the class definition (where `#parse` is in the template definition), I get an empty line in the created file.
**What can I do to have empty lines in my custom template?**

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the `#parse("File Header.java")` under the import statements.

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

import xxx.data.${EntityName};

#parse("File Header.java")
public interface ${NAME} extends BasicService<${EntityName}> {

}
```